# imitate "make -j" from within the Makefile

Tags: shell, make

The shell command `make -j` runs a Makefile's commands in parallel, which is useful on modern multicore CPUs.  Can such parallelism be invoked from *within* a Makefile?

From the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Parallel) for Gnu make, my best guess is using the main Makefile as only a wrapper, which passes `-j` to a sub-make that does the real work.  But maybe there's some environment variable or dot file or internal variable or other ungooglable [snoopy-swearing](https://img1.etsystatic.com/040/0/7319630/il_570xN.592652311_okx1.jpg) way to do this.

It's ok to limit the number of jobs, e.g,. `-j $$(nproc)`.

Probably Linux, but not necessarily.

(Adding something like `alias make='make -j'` to ~/.bashrc is too dangerous;  the decision about whether to parallelize should be per Makefile, not per user.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append to MAKEFLAGS from within the makefile itself, for example:

```
MAKEFLAGS += --jobs=$(CPUS)
```

Where CPUS is defined in the makefile.